# Measuring IOPS in VMWare for an entire datastore

Tags: vmware-vsphere

How can I get a view of current and average IOPS for an entire datastore in vcentre? Ideally in fact I'd like to see IOPS across an entire sDRS pool.

Comment: So you have access to vCenter Operations Management?

Comment: I have the entitlement to use it, though I've never looked at it. Is that the tool for the job?

Comment: Depends on how much of a realtime view you need. I'd really do this at the array level. vCops can give an okay view, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed VCOP, it has been amazing and is totally the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the following script to get the iops of datastore. You can query the esxi host or vcenter.

http://virtualcurtis.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/gathering-virtual-machine-iops-statistics-by-datastore/

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8378981/GatherIOPS.ps1

It will give you an output like this:

VM      Interval (minutes)      Avg Write IOPS      Avg Read IOPS

mssql       30          7           0

mysql       30          1           0

db-sandbox      30      2           0

vcenter     30          8       0

rdp     30          19      4

proxy       30          4       1